# Calculating Percentile by Date

Tags: sas, percentage

I have the following datasets:

```
Date            Primary_Occupation         Jobs
1/1/2005            Math                    23
1/1/2005            Science                 7
1/1/2005            Food                    10
1/1/2006            Math                    10
1/1/2006            Sales                   64
1/1/2006            Transportation          21

All the way until 11/1/2015
```

I am trying to tabulate the percentage of jobs by Primary_Occupation and overtime 
I saw that proc univariate has a bunch of percentile options, but neither of them seem to be the solution for what I am looking to do.

Comment: Can you please help me understand why you need percentile for calculating percentages? you can simply calculate the total jobs across all occupations and then calculate the percentage by dividing individual occupation jobs by total jobs...hint: try proc sql

Comment: Or try proc freq and look at the column/row percentages. You can control what is printed to the table, RTM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template for you to get started. It creates a table with frequencies and percentages. In this example, the output table "summary" contains summary stats for this class of students by sex and age.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
table sex*age / out=summary;
run;
```